# grpc streaming over reverse proxy

Tags: grpc

how exactly does grpc streaming work over reverse-proxies? My understanding is that persistent connections will be made between the client and the reverse proxy, while the connection between the the reverse proxy and my server is not persistent -- so how can my actual servers, sitting behind the reverse proxy, continue to stream messages to the client over the persisted connection?

Also, let's say I want to keep around the persistent connections for handling push notifications (i.e. my server keeps track of the persistent connections, something happens on my server side where i want to notify a particular client, I get the stream / persistent connection for that particular client then send a message over it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gRPC streams use HTTP/2 streams. HTTP/2 streams are bound to the TCP connection they are started on. A reverse proxy will create an HTTP/2 stream to the backend to forward the RPC. So the "stream" will be bound to two TCP connections: client → proxy, proxy → backend. If either TCP connection is closed then the RPC will be cancelled. With HTTP/2, even reverse proxies have a semi-persistent connection to the backend, but it is true they may cycle the connection more frequently than a client may.

Comment: thanks for the answer! i had a quick follow up question to this: how does the proxy keep track of the mappings? i.e. when the server wants to send an event back to the client it will send it to the proxy over the proxy --> backend connection. how does the proxy then find the corresponding  client ---> proxy connection to send the message on?

Comment: The streams all have ids, but it will probably be using some internal data structure to represent streams. So it will be some "stream pointer." If you cross-ref the two pointers into each other's structure, it doesn't even need a hash map. If you look at [this example grpc proxy](https://github.com/ejona86/grpc-java/blob/5f84591f82a049aceb52eb2964ce6e5ae9414d9d/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/grpcproxy/GrpcProxy.java#L58-L59) you'll see the ServerCall listener has a reference to the ClientCall, and the ClientCall listener has a reference to the ServerCall. Basically same approach.